# regex to extract financial amounts from strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to extract sums from some string.

I have this for now

```
values = re.findall(r" \d*[.,]\d+", mystr)
```

I need to match all decimal values even if the have a "." or "," to separate thousands and cents in both the european way and the american one.
Here are a few typical strings:

> DERT-UID: 123456 01 DD. 2014-D C-12 BRUT: 27,50 - COMM 0,37 REF.OP.123

I need the 27,50 and 037

> ALL  /   1000.00/NR.00123456789/KOM.    10.00/DAT.23.123123123123 0

I need the 1000.00 and 10.00

> F 1047 DU 31.12.14

I need nothing but now my regex matches the "31.12" part of the date.

It should also match "1,000.00" or "1.000,00", I don't have examples now but it may happen in the future (or my regex is not good enough to detect them).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex in python:

```
(?<![.,\d])\d+(?:([.,])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?(?!\1)[.,]\d+(?![,.\d])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS8xY7/5)

- `(?![,.\d])` asserts next character after this match is not a digit or dot/comma
- `(?<![,.\d])` asserts previous character after this match is not a digit or dot/comma

Comment: thanks but what about things like "1,000.00" for thousand in the USA and "1.000,00" in UE ?

Comment: I updated code/demo further, see if this suites you.

Comment: `(?:((?!\1)[.,])\d+)+` just makes sure that we don't match `1,000,00` kind of values as a valid match. It does by using a negative lookahead where `\1` is back-reference to first comma or dot.

Comment: now I have an exception `raise error("cannot refer to open group")` do your site use a system incompatible with the re python module ?

Comment: Let me check and revert

Comment: Try: [`(?<![.,\d])\d+(?:([.,])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?(?:((?!\1)[.,])\d+)(?![,.\d])`](https://regex101.com/r/zS8xY7/4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101067/discussion-between-maazza-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
print re.findall("\d+[,\.]\d+",re.sub(r"(\d+[\.,]\d+[\.,])+","",oldstr))
```